# Getting index from Javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

How would I get the index of the chosen element or of 'elems[i]' within the javascript? I know this is a very simple question so any suggestions on a book to buy or course to take would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
    <tr id="subject"><?php 
    $subjects = array("IT","Programming","Networks");
    foreach($subjects as $key => $value) {
    echo "<td>"."<a href='index.php' class='column'>".$value."</a>"."</td>";
    }     
  ?></tr>
    </table>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('column');
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].onclick = function () {
            console.log(this.innerHTML);
        };
    }

</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is a"chosen element"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Please define "_the chosen element_". Do you mean the element currently at hands in the loop? Or perhaps the element which was clicked? Also, `getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an array, it returns a HTMLCollection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('column'); 
 for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) { 
 let a=i;//the magic happens
 elems[i].onclick = function () { 
console.log(a);
 }; 
 }
```

See Closures, let, ES6.

Option two (for older browsers):

```
     var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('column'); 
 for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) { 
 (function(){
 var a=i;
 elems[i].onclick = function () { 
console.log(a);
 }; 
 })();
 }
```

You need to put the index into the handlers scope, either trough using block scoping (let, first answer) or by creating a new scope trough an IIFE...
(You need to create an own scope for each handler)

solution 3:
set the dom objects id:

```
elems[i].id=i;
elems[i].onclick=function(){
  alert(this.id);
};
```

Solution 4:
Get the index dynamically:

```
alert(elems.indexOf(this));
```

Comment: it only prints the amount of elements inside the array. I want it to display the index that was chosen.

Comment: @Solomon: nope. Its the magic let...

Comment: solution 3 seemed to work for me. thanks for all your help!!